# VS Code is using the wrong interpreter/environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, interpreter

I just created a new anaconda environment called "mkg", activated it, and trying to run the code:

```
import torch 
print(torch.__version__)

>>> 1.10.1
```

But this should not work as I don't have torch installed on this environment.
I tried to switch to the new interpreter using `select interpreter` and chose "mkg". Though the code still runs.

This makes me think that either VS Code is using a different interpreter (since I can't seem to see which one is actually being used), or somehow even though I can see that the "mkg" environment is used, it's still somehow using another environment

Comment: you should see interpreter in some `Settings` in some menu in VS Code - and you can change it. You can also use `print( sys.executable )` to get current `/full/path/to/python`. And `print( sys.version )` to get version.

Comment: `print(sys.executable)` shows that it is on another environment, even though in the terminal I see `(mkg) Penguin@Penguin:~/projects/mkg$`

Comment: maybe it activates environment but  in setting it may have different `/full/path/to/python` and use it instead short `python` which should run correct Python.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your steps as you described, but it didn't work on my machine, make sure to create a new environment in a new workspace.

[image]

In addition, you can see the currently used interpreter in the status bar at the bottom of vscode.

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yea this is the first time it ever happens and I created multiple environments before. When you say `create a new environment in a new workspace`, what do you mean? Also, where is the `status bar` at the bottom? I don't see anything like that. On the left I have `main`, and the right I have `jupyter server local, cell 155`

Comment: You can open a new folder as your new workspace. At the bottom of the vscode interface is the status bar.[like this](https://imgur.com/a/mOpqJjY)